# make a button with custom icon

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a button like this :

[image]

So I did this

```
  <div class="d-inline pl-5" style="float:left">
        <button class="btn btn-registerLayout d-inline">
        <i class="icon-play"></i> Login </button>
  </div>
```

and this is css

```
.btn-registerLayout {
background-color: #425fab;
font-size: 10px;
outline: none;   
cursor: pointer;
text-align:left;
height: 20px !important;
width: 50px !important;
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
}
.btn {
 color: #fff !important;
}
.icon-play {
background-image: url(../image/EnterIcon.jpg);    
background-position: right;
display: inline;
height: 20px;  
}
```

the result is like this:

[image]

how can I make that?

Comment: Your code should work, what errors do you get? Is the img in your css dir?

Comment: @Grumpy: I can not see the background image

Comment: Is the link to your icon correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bootstrap icon to achieve this.

```css
.btn.btn-registerLayout {
  background-color: #425fab;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<div class="d-inline pl-5" style="float:left">
  <button class="btn btn-registerLayout d-inline">
         Login <i class="ml-2 bi bi-box-arrow-in-right"></i> </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the HTML, but here is a working example, which you can use as reference.

```css
.btn-registerLayout {
  background-color: #425fab;
  font-size: 10px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  height: 20px !important;
  width: 50px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.btn-registerLayout {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/enter-22-458493.png);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-inline pl-5" style="float:left">
  <button class="btn btn-registerLayout d-inline">Login </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

Note: I change the img to yellow color

```css
.icon-play {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    float: right;

    background-color: yellow;
  
    display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
a.mybtn {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #425fab;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #425fab;
}

a.mybtn i {
  padding-left: 2px;
}

a.mybtn:hover {
  transition: ease-in-out all .3s;
  color: #425fab;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<a class="mybtn" href="#" onclick="#">
  <span>Login<i class="ml-2 bi bi-box-arrow-in-right"></i></span>
</a>
```

Tried to make it as simple as possible, hope it helps.